# Cannot access docker container running locally

Tags: docker

I must be doing something silly. I have docker desktop on my win machine and created a Dockerfile to create a container as follows for a simple echo server.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
#ARG source
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 1234
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/ConsoleApp9.exe"]
```

I build it with the following

```
docker build -t localstuff/dockme .
```

and run it with the following

```
docker run -p 1234:1234 localstuff/dockme
```

According to everything I read , from my laptop I should be able to (telnet 127.0.0.1 1234) and connect to this , as I do when running without the container. No ip works and I'm at a loss.
I docker ps

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
59471be7bf78   localstuff/dockme   "/app/ConsoleApp9.exe"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   0.0.0.0:1234->1234/tcp   amazing_grothendieck
```

I cli the running instance and netstat -a

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:1234         59471be7bf78:0         LISTENING
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any advice please I've been spinning my wheels on this and getting no where.

Comment: Can you check `ConsoleApp9.exe` application listening to `port: 1234` correctly.
 `docker exec <RUNNING_CONTAINER>` then run `netstat -a`. Also check there is no other service is running on `port: 1234`, to do it, you can set different port number.

Comment: Farkhod Thanks for the reply. The app appears to be listening , outside the container works correctly and not exceptions. You can see from my post I did netstat on the cli for the container. I've also changed ports and did 8008, same issue. Do you mean netstat my laptop ? Nothing on 1234. I've read tons of articles and watch ed numerous videos, I'm not sure what is wrong. Only thing is I did not compile the item using docker and am using a base for .net 4.7.2. Not sure why that would matter.

Comment: I've also add a simple telnet client to the image. From the docker console I can connect on the port in the container and send / receive data. Also used a different registry  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base and .Net 6 console. Same issue.

Comment: Someone pointed out that this is probably a docker settings issue. If that helps ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of your firewall rules blocking incoming connections to that port on your host machine,
You can try to disable your firewall and see if you can access to your container
Or if your firewall can, add one rule to your firewall to authorize the port

(Remember to reactivate your firewall after the test !)

Hope it can help you